# I want use elevation only with the text not with the background

Tags: android, material-design

There is a wonderful feature of material design supporting in API 21 is Elevation. I want to use them with a TextView. But when I use it, elevation works on both text and background,but I only want to use elevation with the text not with the background. How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using elevation API. Shadows on Lollipop are drawn using blurred outlines and ViewOutlineProvider can only output simple shapes.

To set a shadow to a TextView, use setShadowLayer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29